# Appending extra rows in dynamically generated list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, checkboxlist

I have a list of checkboxes that are dynamically generated with jquery based on a json object, i need to add one more row with a checkbox "select all" on top of the dynamically genered check boxes, any suggestion on how to do this?

checkbox list would look like this:

```
 - select all (need to add)
 - dynamically generated 1
 - dynamically generated 2
 - dynamically generated 3
 - ...etc
```

Code as follows:

```
function createCheckbox(filtered_array, div_name) {
    var container = $('ul#' + div_name);

    $.each(filtered_array, function (iteration, item) { 
        container.append(
            $(document.createElement("li"))
            .append(
                $('<input />').attr({
                    id: item
                    , name: item
                    , value: item
                    , type: 'checkbox'
                    , checked: true
                })
                //onclick get list of values selected 
                .click(function () {
                    selected_array1 = $('#1_list input:checked').map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
                    selected_array2 = $('#2_list input:checked').map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
                    selected_array3 = $('#3_list input:checked').map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
                    selected_array4 = $('#4_list input:checked').map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
                })
            )
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('label')).attr({
                    'for': item
                })
            .text(item)
            )
        )
    });
}
```

Comment: In your code you are showing already how to add checkboxes, and how to bind event handlers to them. Why not just add one checkbox before the `$.each(filtered_array,...` loop, to select all checkboxes in the `<li>` you create, which you could give an ID also. I am too lazy now to code that for you...

Comment: @MikedeKlerk suggest you post that as an answer.  Nothing says that answers need to go so far as to code things for people, and that seems like a reasonable solution.  (Indeed, it's essentially the one I would have proposed, had you not beat me to it.)

Comment: thank you that solved it, i had tried it initially but had missed something.
Please post as a solution if you'd like.